# Вопрос по ORM в Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Здравствуйте!
Такой вопрос, допустим нужно делать простые операции с таблицей tables, не обязательно же создавать модель class Model_Table extends ORM { }, если я могу сразу обратится $tables = ORM::factory('table')->find_all(); или это есть не хорошо?

Comment: сразу не сможете обратиться, нужно ОРМ Модель описать. А без ОРМ можно через 

DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM table');

Comment: ОК, спасибо! Просто я сначала модель создал, а потом удалил, но обращение к таблице еще почему то работало) Проект закрыл - снова открыл и уже не работало, это меня сбило и я подумал что можно обращаться и так. А можно в одной модели прописать все таблицы, чтобы не создавать несколько моделей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*По логике Коханы*: 1 модел ~ 1 таблица. Если через ОРМ хотите в одном файлике описать все модели то сначала вам нужно описать в виде класса`(в папке application/classess)`.И потом с него екстендит, ну это уже дело вкуса.

!!! Но советую Вам не лениться и `для каждого моделя ОРМ создать свои модели-классы`,верьте это к лучшему. 
Сэкономите **мега время**, при дальнейшем разработке.

Comment: >>"По логике Коханы: 1 модел ~ 1 таблица."<< - Вопросов больше не имею! Спасибо!